# Electric Field of a ring with Electric Potential value given for the ring

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, simulations

I am struggling between connecting a simulation with an analytical equation.

One could calculate the electric field due to a ring with Charge Q, at a certain location on the x-axis using a formula described here.

https://medium.com/swlh/electric-field-due-to-a-uniformly-charged-ring-6b0adcbf7b8d

There are other sources as well for the formula. However in the formula you use a total charge "Q" on the ring. While I am trying to do a simulation in (StarCCM+), to calculate the Electric Field of a charged ring, the simulation is working, however the boundary condition, I could provide is only "Electric Potential", which is also the value I could get from real life conditions.

In real conditions, I am charging a ring by a certain voltage. And it is +/- with a certain frequency.

So how would I convert this voltage (electric potential) value I have to a Charge value on the ring? So I could compare my analytical results with simulation?

Comment: The link that you have provided does not work.

Comment: Going via the [potential route as in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1WMeblOi_o) might be easier although you will need to use Lagrange polynomials and then you should consider what happens if the [conductor has a finite diameter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386845/potential-due-to-a-charged-ring-electric-field-discontinuity).

Comment: How do you define the ring in the simulator? You define it as a circular conductor with finite conductivity? Or you define it as a perfect conductor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem at all. You will have the result different just by a scale. The voltage on the ring depends on the capacitance of the system through which it was charged: $$C = \frac{Q}{V}$$
where V is the ring potential, referenced to the ground of the charging system.
You can write the electric field equation in the provided link in terms of $CV$, and it will be just a scaled version of the one in $Q$. Using a system with higher capacitance gives you the same amount of total charge $Q$ but at lower ring potential, and so on.